# How important is my sitemap architecture

Tags: html, xml, sitemap

I want to know how big a role my site's sitemap architecture is for the google crawl of my site.

Is it important that my products figure on the third layer ?

hope i can find answers

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're submitting a sitemap to google, it will find the pages. Are you talking about the three clicks rule here, in that things should be three clicks away from the homepage? There is a lot more to this than simply sticking to one rule, and the relevance of content on other pages on your site (plus all the usual factors such as inbound links, etc) will all come together to have an effect on how all your pages fare in google search results.

The third layer, or three clicks away from the homepage is a rule that has been around a long time and is good to work towards for the simple fact that people like to find what they want quickly and easily, and nesting important pages deep within the architecture is potentially offputting to people. This alone can affect your google positions - for example if you are getting a lot of clicks to your homepage and google can see that people aren't sticking around and returning to the search results, this is likely to effect your pages positions in the search engines more than anything else as google will potentially treat it as a 'false positive' to some extent. Relevant content on all pages is a good thing in this instance, as is not giving the user endless links to click through to get what they want.

I would recommend signing the site up with google webmasters (http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and keeping an eye on the site in there, and submit a sitemap to google through here too to ensure that they can find all the pages that you want and keep your navigation as straight forward as possible. If they have to be deeper in the architecture than three deep then ensure you are doing everything else you can to ensure that google can understand your site. There is also of course the (probably costly) option of using google adwords to drive targetted traffic to specific pages on your site as well.

To be honest I wouldn't dream of altering a site structure just so the products are a level up if it was completely logical for them to be on the level they are at, assuming that the rest of the pages on the site and everything else is done correctly. So I would say yes the higher the better as it is a part of googles algorithms (afaik) but its no way the be all and end all, if you need them where they are I'd be tempted to put my time into optimising everything else and esssentially making the end user experience the best it can be.

Comment: Dear Matt, Thanks alot for this very complete answer in all terms. I have submitted the site to webmasters. Webmaster tells me through that i have duplicated content on my site. My site is setup in four languages and therefor the same product appears although in the begining of the html URL its indicated thats it a different page. So either i create unique URL corresponding for each language, buy translating the product into the language its filed under. What would you suggest ?